# Default Android host files block Google Analytics?

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-analytics-firebase

I've been working to get Google Analytics v4 set up in my app, but I've been having a few problems.
I'm working with a Galaxy Nexus phone and Google Analytics is being blocked by host files created by AdAway. 
The problem is that I'm don't think I ever installed AdAway and IF at some point maybe I did (or someone else did it on my device) the host files are still on my phone even after doing a factory reset. 
Why would the host files stay on the device ever after resetting the phone?
This is frustrating because I don't see any reason the host files should still be on the on the device and I'm not able to easily collect data on the device about app usage.

Does anyone have any advice about why the host files from AdAway would still be on my device even after resetting it?

Comment: your Android ROM contains AdAway by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just reinstall `AdAway` - if you believe it's the cause of the problem - and select **Disable Ad Blocking**. This should restore the original hosts file that came with your Android firmware.

If that still doesn't work, then you can manually edit the `hosts` file to give you access to Google Analytics. The hosts file is located at `/etc/` directory. Use a file explorer to navigate to this directory and edit/save the `hosts` file with a text editor.

***Note**: You'll need root permission to edit the hosts file under `/etc/` directory since this directory is reserved for system apps or access with root privileges.*

Comment: The problem is that AdAway is no longer on Google Play, so I'm not able to reinstall it. 
(https://sufficientlysecure.org/index.php/adaway/)

I've tried to edit the hosts file with a text editor on the device with no luck. It looks like it's not easy to do since I don't have the required permissions. Any suggestions?

Comment: Download the stock ROM from official website.

Comment: Could you provide a link to the official website? I have very little experience with ROMs and am not quite sure from where to download the stock ROM.

Comment: @user3835623: AdAway is not on Google Play anymore because Google consider the app to be anti-ad - hence it was removed. You can get AdAway from [GitHub](https://github.com/dschuermann/ad-away) if you know how to download source codes, compile and build. Or, get it already built from a group called F-Droid from [here](https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdid=org.adaway). Or, get the last version released by AdAway's original author from [Bittorrent](https://thepiratebay.se/torrent/8322394/AdAway_v2.2_Installer). If AdAway does not work, you may need to install a stock ROM onto your device.

Comment: @user3835623: You'll need root permission to edit the `hosts` file under `/etc/` directory since this directory is reserved for system apps or access with root privileges.